# How to handle assigning string|string[] to type string?

Tags: typescript

The `formidable` module has a `parse` method that returns a parameter `fields` declared in the @types file as follows:

```
export interface Fields {
 [key: string]: string|Array<string>;
}
```

What is a good way assign such a type to a string variable if it is a string or assign `undefined` if it is string[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeof` narrowing should handle this for you:

```
declare const x: string | string[];
let y: string | undefined;
if (typeof x === "string") {
  y = x;
} else { 
  y = undefined;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20const%20x%3A%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20y%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0Aif%20(typeof%20x%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20y%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20y%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)